# Error while managing files from gsutil when the folder contains a ideographic space "\u3000" in Windows?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, gcloud, gsutil

I have to download and sometimes get a list of files in a folder, from a gcloud bucket. The folder names contain Japanese letters. Whenever there is an ideographic space in the names of the folder. gsutil is throwing a `CommandException: One or more URLs matched no objects.` error.

For example, it is working well when I get the files list from the folder `1. 冷蔵定番` but I am getting an error if I do the same from this folder `2. 冷蔵定番　寄り`. The space between those two Japanese words is the ideographic space.

[image: Console output]

I am facing this issue only in Windows OS. I tried it on Linux and it is working fine. I also don't know why it printing something weird in place Japanese characters.

Comment: It's possibly a bug in the Cloud SDK. I recommend you consider filing an issue with Google on the public issue tracker (for Cloud SDK) here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102

Comment: It's good practice to copy-and-paste e.g. Console output into your question. It saves having to traverse an external (and possibly no longer valid) link and it makes it easier for others to parse the question. It's unclear to me why your font renders quotes in italics for example and I'm unclear whether you're using `"` (should) or `“` (should not).

Comment: Have you tried to just save the name in a variable and download it using that? Also, this does seem like a bug in the SDK, so you should report it to the channel @DazWilkin shared

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I filed the issue as @DazWilkin suggested. They were able to reproduce the issue and hence forwarded it to the Google cloud shell engineering team. Here's the issue link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149773533

Comment: @DazWilkin, the quotes are weird because I changed the font in the terminal properties. The default font in terminal wasn't able to show the Japanese characters. It used to show questions marks in place of Japanese characters.

Comment: That's a well-reported issue too: easy to understand and to repro. Well done! Let's hope it's addressed quickly for you.